# how to compare dates in php and sql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a notification system. Shortly.. to compare two dates, the only problem is that i want to compare the months. to see if a month or two have passed from last notification.

i want to use one or two months from  an entry in a mysql database.

the client must select when the notification must come, one or two months.

thank you,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column + INTERVAL 1 MONTH >= NOW()
```

You add 1 (or 2) month to the date of the column in which the date is stored and compare it to the current time "NOW()".

That works with DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns.

Comment: thanks for your help. i have one more question. how can i add to mysql only the day. Can i create a cell and declare it DATE(2)

Comment: why not use a tinyint column?

Comment: i don't know how can i make this. i guessed DATE(2) would work.

Comment: but using a date column for a column that only 31 diffrent values is a waste of memory. Just save the day of a date using the DAY() function (tinyint_day_column = DAY(date_format)).

Comment: thanks for the tip.

i can't get the comparison to work.
the code you've wrote me doesn't work.
i tried this:

`SELECT * FROM ultima_notificare WHERE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month) > 'ultima_notificare'` and some other similar methods but i get only two results: 1. empty result set 2. all of my entries

Comment: You have to add 1 month to your database value, not to NOW() I think. And what are you comparing the date to? For me it seems that you compare it to the table itself. And you shouldn't use single quotes as they might interprent the value as a string and not a column. Use these quotes instead: `´

Answer (score 0):

You can [compare months](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) of two `datetime` columns inside of MySQL.

The only computer-related shortcoming of saying "a month has passed" is that a "month" is an arbitrary unit of time; some have 30 days, others have 31 and one even has 28. I would suggest using the logic of "30 days has passed" because it is based on a set unit of time, a day, which is 86,400 seconds long (with negligible error of course).

Comment: thanks for your help.

i have one more question. how can i add to mysql only the day. Can i create a cell and declare it DATE(2)?

Comment: Just declare it as a `datetime` and use the `day([colname])` function in your select statements.

Comment: i tried something similar but, i want the user to write only the day.

i'm trying to make a notification system and the client must enter only the day that he wants to receive the notification, every month or every two months.

Comment: that might not really work out. What if a users picks the 31st. Will you than only send him a notification every second month?